# What are "piping pickets"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

The phrase is from Rudyard Kipling’s *The Drums of the Fore and Aft*, 1889. A British regiment is facing an Afghan army:

> [T]he lower end of the valley appeared to be filled by an army in position—real and actual regiments attired in red coats, and—of this there was no doubt—firing Martini-Henry bullets which cut up the ground a hundred yards in front of the leading company. Over that pock-marked ground the Regiment had to pass, and it opened the ball with a general and profound courtesy to the **piping pickets**; ducking in perfect time, as though it had been brazed on a rod.

I understand “piping pickets” is figurative language meaning the Afghan soldiers firing at the British. But what, in the literal sense, would a piping picket be?

I suppose *piping* means *pipe-playing*, figuratively meaning shooting. Then my best interpretation is that picket (see [Merriam-Webster](http://beta.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/picket)) refers to a detached group of soldiers guarding an army from surprise ([Oxford Learner’s Dictionaries](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/picket_1?q=picket) says guarding a military base). The reason I’m not entirely satisfied by this is that I don’t think lines of infantrymen at the head of an army engaging the enemy can properly be called a picket, and actual guarding pickets would most likely not play pipes.

A picket may also be people standing or marching in protest, but I cannot see how these would fit.

So is there anything that “piping pickets” literally refers to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a French version of the book, "piping pickets" is translated as "whistling bullets".

This translation can possibly be explained as follow:

- picket bullets are solid base pointed bullets normally cast at home in a gang mold.
- piping is producing a high-pitched or piercing tone.

Comment: Is the French version available online? Coud you share the link?

Comment: @jacinto - It seems that it's no more available on the web :(

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, "**piping**" here means "whistling." Consider:

**boatswain's pipe**

a high-pitched whistle used by a boatswain for giving signals.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/boatswain-s-pipe

A lot like the sound made by a flying bullet, no?

The **pickets**, I'm afraid, are just the pickets: as in "a soldier or detachment of soldiers placed on a line forward of a position to warn against an enemy advance."

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/picket?s=t

Comment: Are you suggesting that the Afghan outliers were whistling, and the British were responding to them? I'm afraid Graffito is correct.